# Hot to get rid of strange object borders

Tags: mesh, edges

I'm following blender guru's tutorial for spaceship corridor and I found out that during panel moddeling phase I've god these strange borders/artifacts.

They are not visible from distance but when I zoom into some distance I can see them during rendering or modeling phase.

As you can see on the third image there is more places with dark areas.

I just joined simple objects like cubes and cylinders.
I have no idea why is this happening.

[image]

[image][image]

-----[image]

Comment: Looks like z-buffer/depth-buffer precision problem to me. What are the dimensions of the scene and the clipping distance of the viewport camera shown in the N-Panel (Select Object, Press N-key -> Transform > Dimensions/ View > Clip: Start/End)?

Comment: The far clipping distance is too big for the viewport to handle in Ortho mode (for your scene dimension). E.g. the effect will increase/decrease with the increase/decrease of the **End** value of the clipping (In fact both values matter). That's because the z-buffer has only a certain amount of precision and can not represent all depths. So the depth test will fail and you will see the faces behind others and get the typical stair step pattern. It's a known and cursed effect in computer graphics and not something special with blender.. ;)

Comment: Yes, I actually discovered it by myself and I was hitting my head - I was playing with start value and not the end value. Thanks!